# create a menu with child and sub child

Tags: php, recursion, treeview, hierarchical

i have this array:

```
 [Label] => Array
            (
                [CMS] => Array
                    (
                        [CMS Settings] => CMS Settings
                        [Content Categories List] => Content Categories List
                        [Extract Pages] => Extract Pages
                        [Manage Affiliate] => Manage Affiliate
                    )

 [Label] => Array
    (
        [CMS] => Array
            (
                [Manage Events] => Array
                    (
                        [Create Events] => Create Events
                        [Event List] => Event List
                    )

                [Manage Highlights] => Array
                    (
                        [Highlights List] => Highlights List
                        [Manage Highlights] => Manage Highlights
                    )

                [Manage Menus] => Array
                    (
                        [List Menus] => List Menus
                    )

                [Manage News] => Array
                    (
                        [List of News] => List of News
                        [Manage News] => Manage News
                    )

                [Manage Web Pages] => Array
                    (
                        [List Web Pages] => List Web Pages
                        [Manage Webpages] => Manage Webpages
                    )

            )

    )
```

as u can see, i have the same name`label` repeated twice in the first one it have one child called `CMS` and with their sub child etc

in the second one i have one child called `CMS` with subchild called `Manage Event` and another child for `Manage Event` called `create events` etc..

i use this recursion function to get this result:

```
foreach($menu as $row){

    $x[$row['parent3']][$row['parent2']][$row['parent1']][$row['pag_desc']]=$row['pag_desc'];
 }
 function recursive($x, $out) {  if (is_array($x)){
   //$out .= "<ul>";
   foreach($x as $i => $data) {

       if ($i === '') {
           $out = recursive($data, $out);
           continue;
       }

       $out .= "<li>";
       if (is_array($data)){
           $out .= ' <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">';
       }
       else
       {
           $out .= '<a href="#">';
       }
       $out .= $i;
       if (is_array($data)){
            $out .= '<b class="caret"></b></a>';
              $out .= "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>";
          $out = recursive($data, $out);
          $out .= "</ul></li>";
       }
       else
       {
           $out .= "</a>";
       }
       if (is_array($data)){

       }
       else
       {
       $out .= "</li>"; 
       }
   }
   }

return $out; }
```

so my question is how to merge them and show under one array called `label` as a parent and under it all the childs and sub childs

thank u in advance

Comment: If I'm understand you correctly, shouldn't `$new = []; $new['label'] = array_merge($firstArray['Label]['CMS'], $secondArray['Label'][CMS']);` work? Read more about [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). i don't really see how your code is related to the arrays and the question, though.